# How to iterate over a list of Map of Strings and add to another list if map contains matching elements on a key value?

Tags: java, list

I have a List of Map<String, String> that I want to iterate over and find the common elements inside the map of string and add to another map.

I am confused what should go inside the if loop to get my expected output. I am looking for comparator type call but I couldn't find that anywhere.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
       if (list.get(i).get("Journal ID").equals(list.get(i+1).get("Journal ID")))
            // ???
         }
      }
```

I was using this method to sort list of Maps. I am expecting some thing like this

```
public Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = new Comparator<>() {
public int compare(Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) {
    return m1.get("Journal ID").compareTo(m2.get("Journal ID"));
    }
       }

     Collections.sort(list, mapComparator);
```

// input and the expected output
my List = [{Journal ID=123, featureID=312},{Journal ID=123, featureID=313},{Journal ID=134,
featureID=314},{Journal ID=123, featureID=1255}]
expected output is one that matching the "Journal ID" [{Journal ID=123, featureID=312},
{ Journal ID=123, featureID=313},{Journal ID=123, featureID=1255}].

Comment: Fix your formatting. Is the last part of the second code sample supposed to be output or commentary?

Comment: What does "find the common elements inside the map of string" mean? You want to find matching keys, matching values, or matching entries (key-value pairs)? A contrived example of input and output would improve your Question.

Comment: That is just the input and the expected output

Comment: Couldn't you just `list.stream().filter()` the list using a combination of `containsKey` and `get`?  Your output of maps containing Journal ID 123 seem to be filtering.  You'd just need to modify the predicate.

Comment: this is just an example, i need the the matching journal ID in the new list , but journal ID "123" is just a random number. Its coming from a database

Comment: What if there are multiple keys with duplicates?

Comment: That will be fine

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to construct a second map which will aggregate all maps.
It will reflect all keys form all maps. As value will be a list of each key value with counters. Implementation can be enhanced also, but the main aspect is how to proceed. Having the aggregate map, then is straight forward to transform in what ever structure needed.

```
public class TestEqMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, String> m1 = Map.of("a","a1","b","b1");
        Map<String, String> m2 = Map.of("a","a1","b","b2");
        Map<String, String> m3 = Map.of("a","a2","b","b2");
        Map<String, String> m4 = Map.of("a","a1","b","b2");
        Map<String, String> m5 = Map.of("a","a3","b","b2");
        AggMap amap = new AggMap();
        amap.addMap(m1);
        amap.addMap(m2);
        amap.addMap(m3);
        amap.addMap(m4);
        amap.addMap(m5);
    
        amap.map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("key="+k+"\n"+v));
    }
    static class AggMap
    {
        public Map<String, ListItem> map = new HashMap<String,ListItem>();
        public void addMap(Map<String,String> m)
        {
            for(String key: m.keySet())
            {
                if(this.map.containsKey(key))
                {
                    this.map.get(key).addItem(m.get(key));
                }
                else
                {
                    ListItem li = new ListItem();
                    li.addItem(m.get(key));
                    this.map.put(key, li);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    static class ListItem
    {
        public List<Item> li = new ArrayList<Item>();
        public ListItem() {};
        public void addItem(String str)
        {
            for(Item i: this.li)
            {
                if(i.val.equals(str))
                {
                    i.count++;
                    return;
                }   
            }
            this.li.add(new Item(str));
            
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
            this.li.forEach(i->sb.append(i+"\n"));
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
    static class Item
    {
        public String val;
        public int count=1;
        
        public Item(String val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }
        
        public String toString()
        {
            return "val="+this.val+" count="+this.count;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key=a
val=a1 count=3
val=a2 count=1
val=a3 count=1

key=b
val=b1 count=1
val=b2 count=4
```

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this.